# Is there a way to grab user's SoundCloud current actions (song change, skip to a certain timestamp, ...)?

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

I am trying to use the SoundCloud API to let the user log into SoundCloud and record all their actions, so I can replicate them in real-time on another device. Is any of this possible?